# Clarification on 人の夢は終わらねェ

Tags: words, spelling

Good evening!

Is 人の夢は終わらねェ the correct spelling for "A man's dream never dies", or is it with a language twist, like someone very specific would spell or say it like that?
I know that the way it's spelled is like "hito no yume wa owara nee", and that the correct japanese version would be "hito no yume wa owaranai", but i'm thinking about getting a tattoo with that, and wanted to know for sure how to do it. Also, it would be divided, 人の夢は on one side, 終わらねェ on the other. What side should each of them be on? 
Thank you very much,

João Reis Santos, Portugal

Comment: Aside from caution with tattos, be careful in ねェ you mixed hiragana and katakana, and I am not sure if this is correct (This is colloquial, there may not be a correct spelling of this). On top, I think that is not pleasing to the eye on a typographical level. You may rather use ねぇ　or ねえ　or even ね〜...

Comment: @Urukann I think that ねェ is not a big problem here, native speakers [do that too](http://youtu.be/OWl6bvSx0ME).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to look at to confirm... Anyway, I provided typographical alternatives just in case !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're *really* interested only in grammatical and semantic clarification, yes, you are understanding that sentence correctly. That would be still somewhat funny to the eyes of native speakers by its nature, but at least you don't have to worry about your tattoo being listed in [sites like this](http://tokyodesu.com/2013/08/09/pictures-terrible-kanji-tattoos-with-their-english-translations/).

If you want to separate that sentence into two lines, yes, breaking after は is OK. 人の夢は means "man's dream," and 終わらない, "never ends." I'm not sure what you mean by *side*, but neither 人の夢は nor 終わらない would make sense alone. If you want it to be understandable as a meaningful message, it would be better to keep them together.

Comment: You wouldn't screw with a "Coffin Dude" or a "Pull Dude Power Bastard", I guess.

Comment: Thank you brother, that was extremely heplful :) Have a nice day!

Comment: What's a more natural way to say, "A man's dream never dies"? Btw, thanks for the tattoo link haha.

Comment: Well, 人の夢は終わらねェ would be completely natural on a T-shirt ([like this](http://item.rakuten.co.jp/prince-sports/12ja5t8614/)), but when it comes to tattoos...sorry I have no idea.